# Convert multilanguage database design into JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am designing a multilanguage system using Java, and during my research to find the best database model to store multi-localized text, I came accross Vertabelo's blog and this wonderful design, [from here](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system):

[Database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8km9T.png)

However, as there are lots of objects to be localized in the project, I am avoiding to write all the Dao's myself, and stick with JPA, if possible.

The thing is that I don't know much of JPA yet, so I googled for available solutions to this problem, and found another great blog post (which fortunatelly addresses the same design shown in Vertabelo's blog here: https://thoughts-on-java.org/localized-data-hibernate/)

```
    @Entity
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    public class LocalizedProduct {

        @EmbeddedId
        private LocalizedId localizedId;

        @ManyToOne
        @MapsId("id")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private Product product;

        private String name;

        private String description;

        ...

}



@Embeddable
public class LocalizedId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1089196571270403924L;

    private Long id;

    private String locale;

    public LocalizedId() {
    }

    public LocalizedId(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    // getter and setter methods ...
{

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Supplier supplier;

    private Double price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "localizedId.locale")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private Map<String, LocalizedProduct> localizations = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public String getName(String locale) {
        return localizations.get(locale).getName();
    }

    public String getDescription(String locale) {
        return localizations.get(locale).getDescription();
    }
}

Product p = new Product();
p.setPrice(19.99D);

LocalizedProduct lpDe = new LocalizedProduct();
lpDe.setId(new LocalizedId("de"));
lpDe.setProduct(p);
lpDe.setName("Hibernate Tips - Mehr als 70 Lösungen für typische Hibernateprobleme");
p.getLocalizations().put("de", lpDe);

LocalizedProduct lpEn = new LocalizedProduct();
lpEn.setId(new LocalizedId("en"));
lpEn.setProduct(p);
lpEn.setName("Hibernate Tips - More than 70 solution to common Hibernate problems");
p.getLocalizations().put("en", lpEn);

em.persist(p);
```

Then comes the problem I wanna solve.

The solution presented in "thoughts-on java" retrieves an object holding a map with all translations from all languages attached in it, and this behavior is not desired, as my system is going to present data in at least 104 languages, eventually.

**The question is:** is there a way to tune this solution in order to be able to query for an object passing Entity id and Locale id and get a translated object to a single language at a time?

Answer (score 1):

For the possible variants, the following is simplest/concize:

```
class Product {
    long id;

    InternationalText name;
    InternationalText description;
}

class InternationalText {
    long id;
}

class LocalizedText {
    long id;

    InternationalText international;
    Locale locale;
    String text;
}
```

As the InternationalText is not really needed, it does not need a `List<LocalizedText>` ONE_TO_MANY field. On loading a `product.name` you do not want to load all languages.

I leave the details to you, as you should in a separate prototype try it out; work all details; how to do things. Debugging that things indeed are lazily loaded etcetera.

Comment: Hi @Joop, thanks for answering my question. Not sure if I understood your variant though, it seems like all entities would end up storing translations in a single multilingual table, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that variant. In some regards not perfect. But minimal w. r. t. the DB schema. P. S. good namens matter.

Comment: Yeah, good input. Would give a +1 but SO won't let me yet, too novice for that :P
But the thing is that I would rather, in this project, stick with a translation table per entity, otherwise it would give me a giant single table, which would be harder to maintain. I will answer bellow the approach I am heading to, so far.

Comment: That is absolutely fine too. Especially product names and descriptions I already did in similar approach. One still can write generic code that can maintain texts, imports. One thing: I also used xml based translation memories as source for filling the database. Say if you outsource some translations for a specific languages.